# Can a dynamic method in C# 4 be used to return a different data type with each call?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

If I have a dynamic method in C# 4. Can it be used to return for example in 1 call - A string, in another call a Boolean, and in another call an int?

Or is the return type of the dynamic method set after the first runtime call? Meaning if the first time I call the method it returns a boolean, must all subsequent calls to that method also return boolean?

Answer (score 8):

A `dynamic` method is free to change it's return data at any point it chooses.  For example

```
class Example {
  private int m_count;
  public dynamic GetData() {
    switch(m_count++) {
      case 0: return 42;
      case 1: return "hello world";
      default: return new object();
    }
  }
}
```

A `dynamic` typed method is little different than a method that has an `object` return type.  It's free to return any values which are compatible with `object`.  The only issue is ensuring the caller of the method can handle the various values.

Comment: I'm loving C# 4. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: C# 4 seems to be like VBScript 98 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Any object can be converted to dynamic type implicitly, so you should be able to to do so. Dynamic in most cases functions like type `object`.